# Probability that the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix being positive

Tags: probability

> Let $M$ be a $2\times2$ matrix such that every entry is equal to $0$ or $1$. Supposing that the value chosen for every entry is indepent from each other and that every choice has equal probability to be either $0$ or $1$, calculate the probability that the determinant of $M$ being positive.

I think i'm into the right way. I just dunno how to calculate the probability using the properties. Here what i tought:

Let $p$ denote the probability associated with every entry. Let det$M$ = $a_1a_4 - a_3a_2$. We define the following events:

$A_i=$ the product $a_1a_4$ is equal to $i$, where $i=0,1$.

$B_i$= the product $a_3a_2$ is equal to $i$, where $i=0,1$.

$E_{kj}$ = the entrance $a_k$ has value $j$, for $k=1,...,4$ and $j=0,1$.

The event $F$: the determinant is positive happens when the determinant is equal to zero or one. Ie, $F=D_0\cup D_1$, where $D_i$= the determinant has value $i$, for $i=0,1$.

Therefore, we may write:

$D_0 = A_1B_1 \cup A_0B_0$

$D_1=A_1B_0$

And

$A_1=E_{11}E_{41}$

$B_1=E_{31}E_{21}$

$A_0=E_{10}E_{41}\cup E_{11}E_{40} \cup E_{10}E_{40}$

$B_0=E_{21}E_{30}\cup E_{20}E_{31}\cup E_{20}E_{30}$.

Now: how can i continue in order to calculate the probability? $D_0$ and $D_1$ are mutually exclusive?

Comment: There are only 16 matrices to check, no need to be fancy!

Comment: “The determinant is positive” means that it is *greater than* zero. Equal to zero is not one of the desired results.

Comment: The term is an **entry**, not entrance, by the way.

Comment: You are in a case where the "universe" has $2^4=16$ elements. You can describe easily all the elements...from $\binom{0 \ 0}{0 \ 0}$ to $\binom{1 \ 1}{1 \ 1}$. Thus the answer is almost instantaneous by pure inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by counting the matrices with zero determinant.  There are $5$ matrices with at least $3$ zeros.  Of the matrices with two zeros, $4$ of them have a zero row.  Finally, the matrix with no $0$s has a zero determinant.  That's a total of $10$ matrices with determinant $0$.

So, there are $6$ matrices (of the $16$ matrices in total) with non-zero determinant.  Half of these must have a positive determinant (for any matrix with positive determinant, we can switch the rows to make a matrix with negative determinant!)

Conclude that there are $3$ matrices with positive determinant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "positive" you mean $\ge 0$. The only way to make the determinant strictly negative is to have  $a_1a_4 =0$ and $a_3a_2 =1$; the former happens with probability $3/4$ and the latter with probability $1/4$ so since they are all independent, they happen simultaneously with probability $3/16$. Otherwise the determinant is positive with probability $13/16$.

Comment: Alternatively: note that the matrix is "positive" with a zero entry if and only if $a_1 = 0$ or $a_4 = 0$. Then, $\frac 12 + \frac 12 - \frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 = \frac{12}{16}$.  The matrix with just $1$s appears with probability $\frac 1{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that swapping two rows of a matrix causes a sign change in determinant.  So for every matrix with determinant $1$, you get a matrix of determinant $-1$ by swapping the rows of that $2\times 2$ matrix.  This means that there are an equal number of matrices with determinant $1$ and $-1$.  So if you can find the number of matrices with determinant $0$, then we're basically done, since as someone pointed out in the comments, you can just write down all $16$ such matrices.

There are $10$ matrices with determinant $0$, which implies that there are $10$ with nonzero determinant.  By our logic above, we conclude that there are exactly $3$ matrices with positive determinant.

Edit:  Looks like I got beat to the answer!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're correct, silly mistake on my part.

Comment: You still seem to have miscounted: you say 5 matrices with positive determinant.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks for the correction.